# Probability Distribution - Discrete Maths

Tags: probability-distributions

A string consisting of $A$s, $B$s and $C$s is chosen uniformly at random from the set $\{BBBBB, ABBBC, AACCC, ABBCC, BBBBC \}$.

Let $X$ be the number of $A$s in the string.

Give the probability distribution of $X$.

Do i assume $X$ as the number of $A$'s in the set which will be $X= \{0,1,2\}$ . If so how do i continue as the question is quite new to me .

Comment: Your assuming is a good start. For $p(X)$ there is 2 strings out of 5 where $X=0$, 2 out of 5 where $X=1$ and one case with $X=2$. What are the probabilities those cases to occur?

Answer (score 1):

So we have that the probability that $X = 0$ occurs if $BBBBB$ or $BBBBC$ is chosen. Hence $X=0\ w.p.\ 2/5$.

Then $X=1$ occurs if $ABBBC$ or $ABBCC$ is chosen. Hence $X=1\ w.p.\ 2/5$.

I let you finish !

Answer (score 0):

Here $\Omega:=\{BBBBB, ABBBC, AACCC, ABBCC, BBBBC \}$.

It is equipped with $\sigma$-algebra $\wp(\Omega)$ and with a probability measure $P$ defined by $P(E)=\frac15|E|$.

This together makes $\langle\Omega,\wp(\Omega),P\rangle$ a probability space.

Then $X:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ is prescribed by: $$\omega\mapsto\text{number of }A\text{s in string }\omega$$

$X$ will take values in $\{0,1,2\}$.

Here e.g. $\{X=1\}=\{\omega\in\Omega\mid X(\omega)=1\}=\{ABBBC,ABBCC\}$ so that $$P(\{X=1\})=P(\{ABBBC,ABBCC\})=\frac25$$

It is common to abbreviate $P(\{X=1\})$ by $P(X=1)$.

Another way to write the result is: $P_X(1)=\frac25$.

Comment: so for p({X=2})=1/5 and for P({X=0})=2/5 ??

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: and that will be my final answers right . I can put it in a form of table right ??

Comment: Yes, it is complete. I would just mention the $3$ probabilities you found together with the statement that $X$ only takes values in $\{0,1,2\}$.

Comment: i am so sorry but I got confused for p(X=0) . By right that should mean that there are no A's right . So what will the probability be ?

Comment: $\{X=0\}=\{BBBBB,BBBBC\}$ so that $P(\{X=0\})=P(\{BBBBB,BBBBC\})=\frac25$